# How fix this "AttributeError at /contact/" Django Error?

Tags: python, django, forms, view

AttributeError at /contact/

'ContactForm' object has no attribute 'clean_data'

These is my view:

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        topic = form.clean_data['topic']
        message = form.clean_data['message']
        sender = form.clean_data.get('sender', 'noreply@example.com')
        send_mail(
            'Feedback from your site, topic: %s' % topic,
            message, sender,
            ['antoniomaestre7@gmail.com']
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
else:
    form = ContactForm(initial={'topic':'Write your topic here', 'message' : 'Write your message here','sender':'Sender'})
return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form})
```

and there is my forms.py file:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
topic = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
sender = forms.EmailField(required = False)

def clean_message(self):
    message = self.clean_data.get('message', '')
    num_words = len(message.split())
    if num_words < 4:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
    return message
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: It's `cleaned_data` not `clean_data`.

Comment: ooh thanks. It works!!